# Why does gdb-mi not support async target feature?

Tags: gdb

Based on the gdb/mi documentation at `https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/GDB_002fMI-Support-Commands.html`, I've run this

```
$ gdb --quiet -i=mi $(readlink -f $(which ls))
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
=cmd-param-changed,param="confirm",value="off"
~"Reading symbols from /nix/store/6m648r8w4qhqv8c33n09blp389bsvvx4-coreutils-8.25/bin/ls..."
~"(no debugging symbols found)...done.\n"
(gdb) 
-list-target-features
^done,features=[]
```

How can I find out why `async` is not in the list of target features? Given that emacs tries to use the `async` functionality by default in its gdb integration, I would expect this feature to be pretty standard.

I'm on gdb version `7.11.1`.

Comment: What is your OS and CPU? Where did you find your gdb, in os package manager or compiled it youself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-list-target-features` is a bit funny.  In order to see `async` there, you must do two things:

1. Before starting the inferior, `-gdb-set mi-async on`.  (There's also a deprecated alias for compatibility with older versions; see the manual.)
2. Only check `-list-target-features` after the inferior has started.

With these I get:

```
-list-target-features
^done,features=["async"]
```

This all seems obscure to the point of not being useful; but I think it was done this way for compatibility when async was made the default internally.